# e.KeyCode Doesn't want to work for me

Tags: vb.net, keypress

So I am trying to write some simple code that toggles something on or off when the key "g" is pressed. I'll let you take a look at the code and hopefully it is something staring me in the face...

```
    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.G Then
        If Label2.Text = "Off" Then
            Label2.Text = "On"
            Label2.ForeColor = Color.Green
        Else
            Label2.Text = "Off"
            Label2.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have somehow lost the "**Handes Me.KeyDown**" on the end your handler...note the end of the first line:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.G Then
        If Label2.Text = "Off" Then
            Label2.Text = "On"
            Label2.ForeColor = Color.Green
        Else
            Label2.Text = "Off"
            Label2.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Also, make sure you've got the **KeyPreview** property of your **Form** set to True.